# Slim fails to run with error msg about log file

Tags: login

I'm trying to run SLiM login manager, but allays get next error message

```
slim: closing Log file, while is already closed
```

There are no similar bug reports on the internet, and I have absolutely no idea about this error.

[My /etc/slim.conf](http://pastie.org/4293663)

```
# Path, X server and arguments (if needed)
# Note: -xauth $authfile is automatically appended
default_path        /bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
default_xserver     /usr/bin/X
xserver_arguments -nolisten tcp vt07

# Commands for halt, login, etc.
halt_cmd            /sbin/shutdown -h now
reboot_cmd          /sbin/shutdown -r now
console_cmd         /usr/bin/lilyterm -x "/bin/cat /etc/issue; exec /bin/login"
#suspend_cmd        /usr/sbin/suspend

# Full path to the xauth binary
xauth_path         /usr/bin/xauth 

# Xauth file for server
authfile           /var/run/slim.auth


# Activate numlock when slim starts. Valid values: on|off
# numlock             on

# Hide the mouse cursor (note: does not work with some WMs).
# Valid values: true|false
# hidecursor          false

# This command is executed after a succesful login.
# you can place the %session and %theme variables
# to handle launching of specific commands in .xinitrc
# depending of chosen session and slim theme
#
# NOTE: if your system does not have bash you need
# to adjust the command according to your preferred shell,
# i.e. for freebsd use:
# login_cmd           exec /bin/sh - ~/.xinitrc %session
login_cmd           exec /bin/bash -login ~/.xinitrc %session

# Commands executed when starting and exiting a session.
# They can be used for registering a X11 session with
# sessreg. You can use the %user variable
#
# sessionstart_cmd  some command
# sessionstop_cmd  some command

# Start in daemon mode. Valid values: yes | no
# Note that this can be overriden by the command line
# options "-d" and "-nodaemon"
# daemon  yes

# Available sessions (first one is the default).
# The current chosen session name is replaced in the login_cmd
# above, so your login command can handle different sessions.
# see the xinitrc.sample file shipped with slim sources
sessions            awesome

# Executed when pressing F11 (requires imagemagick)
screenshot_cmd      import -window root /slim.png

# welcome message. Available variables: %host, %domain
welcome_msg         Welcome to %host

# Session message. Prepended to the session name when pressing F1
# session_msg         Session: 

# shutdown / reboot messages
shutdown_msg       The system is halting...
reboot_msg         The system is rebooting...

# default user, leave blank or remove this line
# for avoid pre-loading the username.
#default_user        simone

# Focus the password field on start when default_user is set
# Set to "yes" to enable this feature
#focus_password      no

# Automatically login the default user (without entering
# the password. Set to "yes" to enable this feature
#auto_login          no


# current theme, use comma separated list to specify a set to 
# randomly choose from
current_theme       default

# Lock file
lockfile            /var/lock/slim.lock

# Log file
logfile             /var/log/slim.log
```

Answer (score 1):

How and where did you install slim? (and which version?)

I had the same problem after an upgrade, because my themes were installed in `/usr/share/slim/themes`, whereas slim 1.3.4 was expecting them in `/usr/local/share/slim/themes`. If that is your problem, then adding a symlink (or moving files) should solve the issue.

Also check `/var/log/slim.log` (although in my case, slim 1.3.4 does not seem to log errors properly).